# Relation property : EditGuesser, ReferenceArrayInput and CheckboxGroupInput

Tags: rest, checkbox, relationship, react-admin

I want to use a CheckboxGroupInput to modify a OneToMany property (account).
I have code that works with an ArrayInput and many list, but I don't find it practical and would prefer to use checkboxes.
I managed to display the list of checkboxes but the items are not pre-selected in EditGuesser.

This is my react admin code :

```
<EditGuesser transform={AggregationTransform} actions={<EditActions />}>
            <ArrayInput source="account" label="Comptes">
                <SimpleFormIterator inline disableReordering fullWidth>
                    <ReferenceInput source="@id" reference="accounts">
                        <SelectInput optionText="name" fullWidth label="Compte"/>
                    </ReferenceInput>
                </SimpleFormIterator>
            </ArrayInput>

            <ReferenceArrayInput source="account.id" reference="accounts">
                <CheckboxGroupInput source="account.@id" label="Comptes" row={false} />
            </ReferenceArrayInput>
</EditGuesser>
```

Here is my main API return's :

```
{
    "@context": "\/contexts\/Aggregation",
    "@id": "\/aggregations",
    "@type": "hydra:Collection",
    "hydra:totalItems": 1,
    "hydra:member": [
        {
            "@id": "\/aggregations\/1",
            "@type": "Aggregation",
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Veniam quisquam dolorem qui ea inventore.",
            "account": [
                {
                    "@id": "\/accounts\/4",
                    "@type": "Account",
                    "id": 4,
                    "bank": "\/banks\/2",
                    "name": "Repudiandae est delectus ullam laudantium."
                },
                {
                    "@id": "\/accounts\/2",
                    "@type": "Account",
                    "id": 2,
                    "bank": "\/banks\/2",
                    "name": "Veniam quisquam dolorem qui ea inventore."
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Accounts api return :

```
{
    "@context": "\/contexts\/Account",
    "@id": "\/accounts",
    "@type": "hydra:Collection",
    "hydra:totalItems": 2,
    "hydra:member": [
        {
            "@id": "\/accounts\/2",
            "@type": "Account",
            "id": 2,
            "bank": {
                "@id": "\/banks\/2",
                "@type": "Bank",
                "name": "Bank 2"
            },
            "name": "Veniam quisquam dolorem qui ea inventore.",
            "officialLabel": "Facilis enim repellat quae et maiores sint dicta.",
            "position": 4,
            "history": true
        },
        {
            "@id": "\/accounts\/4",
            "@type": "Account",
            "id": 4,
            "bank": {
                "@id": "\/banks\/2",
                "@type": "Bank",
                "name": "Bank 2"
            },
            "name": "Repudiandae est delectus ullam laudantium.",
            "officialLabel": "Aspernatur voluptatem repudiandae ullam incidunt.",
            "position": 97,
            "history": true
        }
    ],
    "hydra:view": {
        "@id": "\/accounts?history=true",
        "@type": "hydra:PartialCollectionView"
    },
    "hydra:search": {
        "@type": "hydra:IriTemplate",
        "hydra:template": "\/accounts{?history}",
        "hydra:variableRepresentation": "BasicRepresentation",
        "hydra:mapping": [
            {
                "@type": "IriTemplateMapping",
                "variable": "history",
                "property": "history",
                "required": false
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

package.json react-admin version : 4.16.1

```
{
  "name": "react-fin",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@api-platform/admin": "^3.4.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.6",
    "@types/node": "^20.8.9",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.33",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.14",
    "echarts": "^5.4.3",
    "echarts-for-react": "^3.0.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^5.3.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Regards

Comment: I don't think `<ReferenceArrayInput>` is the right component to use here. It expects its `source` field to be an array, but `account.id` is not.

Since you are dealing with an array of objects (`account`), not an array of ids, I believe you have no choice but to use `<ArrayInput>`.

Comment: Thanks, but the code below is giving me the following error : "_If you're not wrapping the CheckboxGroupInput inside a ReferenceArrayInput, you must provide the choices prop_"

`<ArrayInput source="account" label="Comptes"><CheckboxGroupInput source="@id" label="Comptes" row={false} /></ArrayInput>`

I don't know how to add a choices parameters with ArrayInput

Comment: I believe the problem is in your data model. If 'aggregations' holds a 1-n reference to 'accounts', then it should only contain the accounts ids. If you decide to store complete 'accounts' objects inside 'aggregations', then you need an `ArrayInput` to edit all their fields. If you change the model to hold an array of ids only, then you will be able to use `ReferenceArrayInput` + `CheckboxGroupInput`.

Comment: Thank you, I have tested it, but I must not know how to use the api property array `account : ["/accounts/4", "/accounts/2"]` but the result is the same. The list of labeled checkboxes is displayed, but no box is pre-selected.